# Specify options for multiple modals - Materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I am designing a webpage with 2 materialize modals. I want to set `dismissible:false` for both of them, but it only seems to work with one. The documentation is pretty vague on how to specify which modal you are setting options for, and right now it only works with the first modal. Here is the code where I set the dismissible option to false:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
        dismissible: false
    });
});
```

And here is the html for the modals:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="forgotPasswordPIN" class="modal col s10 offset-s1 m8 offset-m2 l6 offset-l3">
        <form name="emailForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4>Forgot PIN/Password</h4>
                <span class="flow-text">Send PIN and password to: </span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input required id="email" type="text" style="font-size:175%;" name="email" ng-model="email" ng-minlength="2" ng-pattern="/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/"/>
                    <label for="email" class="flow-text">Email</label>
                    <div ng-messages="emailForm.email.$error">
                        <div class="red-text" ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
                        <div class="red-text" ng-message="pattern">Invalid Email</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#!" id="send" Text="Send"  ng-click="sendClick()" ng-show="emailForm.$valid" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">Send</a>
                <a class="btn disabled" ng-hide="emailForm.$valid">Send</a>
                <a href="" ng-click="cancelClick()" style="margin-right:25px;" class="blue-grey lighten-2 btn waves-effect waves-light">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="bottomModal" class="modal bottom-sheet">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4 id="successTitle">Email Sent</h4>
        <p id="successContent">
            Your password will be sent to <span ng-bind="email"></span>.<br /> Please allow up to 10 minutes for the email to be received.
        </p>

        <h4 id="errorTitle">Invalid Email</h4>
        <p id="errorContent" class="red-text">
            Sorry, we do not recognize that email. Please try again.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I specify which modal I am setting options for? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My main issue is that I am opening the second one programmatically, and not with an anchor tag. In Materialize documentation the only way it shows to set options is according to the trigger, or anchor tag. So I may not be able to do it without using an actual trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was asked a while ago, but maybe someone else is having similar issues.

If you use the modal options, as listed by the OP, inside the function you use to open the modal it will work.

For example:

```
  $('#bottomModal').openModal({
    dismissible: false
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to initialize both modals in different calls, using different classes. Doing that you can use different parameters to each one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.modal-trigger1').leanModal({
    dismissible: false
  });
 $('.modal-trigger2').leanModal({
    dismissible: false
  });
});
//Them:
<a class="modal-trigger1 waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#forgotPasswordPIN">Modal</a>
<a class="modal-trigger2 waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#bottomModal">Modal</a>
```

Comment: So, my issue is that I don't trigger the second one with an anchor tag. I open it programmatically from javascript. Is there any way to do that without a second trigger?